# Function namespacing issues in D

Tags: d

Say I have a class Foo with a member function bar(). I also have a completely unrelated function which happens to be named bar() as well.

```
class Foo {
    /* ... */
    void bar() {
        /* ... */
    }
}

void bar() { /* ... */ }
```

It seems that any call to bar() from within Foo defaults to the member function.

How do I call the non-member function from inside Foo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this:

```
.bar();
```

The leading `.` will force the compiler to look at the module-level scope.

You can also use the fully-qualified name: `module_name.bar()`, where `module_name` is the name of the module (by default, the filename without the `.d` extension).